# How to correctly redirect to the login page with React

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-dom

I have the following (redux) state:

```js
{
  authentication: user
}
```

When logged out, `user` is set to `null`.

I have the following components:

```js
const Dashboard = ({ authentication }) => {

  if (!authentication.user) {
    return <Redirect to={"/login"} />
  }

  return (
    <SomeInnerComponent />
  );
}

const SomeInnerComponent = ({ authentication }) => {

  const name = authentication.user.name;

  return (
    <h1>Hello, {name}</h1>
  )
}
```

`authentication` is mapped using `connect` and `mapStateToProps`. I would think that when I am logged out that I would be redirected, but I get an error instead: `authentication.user is null`.

Why does the `if`-statement in `Dashboard` not redirect me? I also tried wrapping it in a `useEffect` with `authentication` as a dependency.

Comment: return <Redirect to={"/login"} />

Comment: Yes sorry, it's `return <Redirect to={"/login"} />` in my code already, updated my question.

Comment: well.. what is `authentication` before the `if`-clause? did you log it? **edit:** obviously, it is not null ;)

Comment: @bbortt `console.log(authentication)` gives: `Object { user: null }`. But I'm not checking for `authentication`, I'm checking on `authentication.user`.

Comment: @Titulum I know, but it gives hints about the `user` anyways ;) **Edit:** So, as this code looks fine. Where do you use `Dashboard`? Can you show us the `mapStateToProps` as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by writing a custom hook:

```js
export function useAuthentication() {

  const history = useHistory();
  const user = useSelector(state => state.authentication.user);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!user) {
      history.push(LOGIN);
  });

  return { user };
}
```

Which can then be called in my React components as follows:

```js
const Dashboard = () => {
  const { user } = useAuthentication();

  return (
    // My code
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In our app, we redirect unauthenticated users by history.replace [history docs](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/master/docs/Navigation.md)
or you read docs again, maybe you can find mistake in your code [reacttraining](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect)